# get bound data on click event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my Razor Page containing multiple divs with each div containing either follow or unfollow button with NeighbourhoodName and other stuff.

```
 <p class="lead" style="display: none" data-bind="visible: profiles().length == 0">No neighbourhood found...</p>
 <ul data-bind="visible: profiles().length > 0, foreach: profiles">
 <li class="media" style="border-top: solid 1px lightgrey; padding-top: 15px;">    
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
            <a class="btn pull-right" data-bind="visible: !IsFollowed, attr: { href: followAction }">Follow</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-bind="visible: IsFollowed, attr: { href: unfollowAction }">Unfollow</a>
        </h4>
        <em data-bind="text: NeighbourhoodName"></em>
        <em data-bind="text: NeighbourhoodId"></em>

    //stuck at this line
        <a href="/Neighbourhood/NeighbourhoodDetail/@Neig"> </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to Generate a new page with click on any of the div. So,I want to send id of the neighbourhood to action method with click on respective div. Right now, i am able to get NeighbourhoodId with data-bind attribute but dont know how to send this id to action method with click on any area of div means how to mix this anchor tag. something like that.

This is my follow action url in a knockout code which send neighbourhoodId on follow button click:

```
 self.followAction = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/Neighbourhood/Follow?uid=' + data.NeighbourhoodId;
```

But, i dont want any button. simple click on div should send id to action method.
how to achieve this. please suggest me something.

Comment: Do you want something like https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/jp19kdgz/ ? you can do anything you want in onclick function..correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yupp something like that but i want to append neighbourhoodId  okk well good point , it may be possible with on function but i want to know how to get neighbourhoodid from a data-bind attribute here @debin

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use the [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) on the div, and bind it to a function in your viewmodel.

The function in your viewmodel receives as parameter the knockout context available in the bound element. So, you can directly access the desired data from that function.

```
<div class="media-body" data-bind="click: yourViewModelFunction">
```

In your viewmodel, your function should be implemented like this:

```
yourViewModelFunction = function(data) {
  // here you can use data.NeighbourhoodId
}
```